# Initalize a Future List in a bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

How can I initialize my Future<List<Pokemon>> in the super constructor ?

```
class PokedexBloc extends Bloc<PokedexEvent, Future<List<Pokemon>>> {
  PokedexBloc() : super(Future<Pokemon[]>()) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a Future as a state. You'd have to use e.g. `List<Pokemon>`